# How to display UI and li inline

Tags: angularjs, html

I've some thing like below

```
<ul ng-repeat="country in countries">
    <li ng-repeat="state in country.states">
        {{state.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Consider, Each country has one state. I want to display all state names in-line.

Ex: `State1  State2 State3` ...

Not like (by default)

```
State1
State2
State3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try need to add this style to your page.

```
<style>
    ul li{display:inline}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

use display inline CSS tag for li
`li {
display:inline;
}`